# Strange colors on monitor AOC V22 (NVIDIA GeForce 210)

Tags: graphics-card, display, colors

There is the picture from my monitor - I take that picture with my phone. If I printscreen it, you probably wouldn't see the problem with colours.
[image: HomeAlone]

I already check, if dispay adapters are up to date and they are (Intel(R) HD Graphics and NVIDIA GeForce 210). Maybe there should't be both of them installed? But on the other side, they are installed for a long time - the problem with colours is not so old.

I reseted my monitor in its OSD menu.

I was trying something in Settings/Display/Advanced display settings/Color management and Color calibration also. But it looks for me, that the problem is somewhere else. Or I missed something?

Also I was trying something in NVIDIA ControlPanel/Adjust desktop color settings, but the result was the same as previous Color calibration/Color management.

Comment: Try the basics: reconnect cables, try a new/different video cable, and try a different monitor to determine if it's the monitor or the video card.

Comment: 1. I try the same monitor with different D-SUB cable. The problem stays. 2. I try with an extra (different) monitor and the colours of other monitor are perfect. Any other sugestions how to fix my problem?

Comment: It's the monitor. Is there anythink I can do (besides buying new one)?

Comment: @bearboar is correct... troubleshooting 101, replace each piece and you will find the definitive source of the problem. Only 3 pieces are involved here, the monitor, video cable, and video card. Swapping monitors proves the video card (and drivers, etc) are good, swapping cables proves they are not the cause, that only leaves the monitor... You have reset everything to it's defaults and the problem remains, thus the issue is hardware. That monitor is from early 2009, meaning it's 7.5 years old, well beyond the anticipated product life of 3-6 years.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your system.  That kid has a horrible skin condition.  :-)  It looks like something in the chain (image, monitor setting, etc.), has gone to 8 bit color.  It's just run out of colors for smooth gradients.